# How to change the mouse cursor into a custom icon or image?

Tags: css, icons, cursor

I have a plan to change the mouse cursor to an blood icon when mouse is hovering on some elements.

the link of icon that I wanted to change.
[https://www.flaticon.com/free-icon/blood_603227?term=blood&page=1&position=11&page=1&position=11&related_id=603227&origin=tag](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6mpvV.png)

Answer (score 2):

Try this, insert your image instead of the placeholder.

```css
body {
  cursor: url("https://via.placeholder.com/20"), auto;
}

div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: teal;
}

div:hover {
  cursor: url("https://via.placeholder.com/10"), auto;
}
```

```html
<div>Hover me</div>
```